# Highlight search term in javascript according to term

Tags: javascript

example :

I want to search for "ency" (encyclopedia).

the result will be : encyclopedia  the search result will be highlighted using the number of characters ->  encyclopedia

WIll try to clear my point.... :

Ency -> **ency**clopedia

Encycl - > **encycl**opedia

any idea how to do it...  ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please provide with some code you have tried till now?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/method-like-string-contains-in-javascript check if this helps you in anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you are ready to use jQuery then it is easier:

```
var searchPattern = new RegExp(searchString, 'g');
$elem.html($elem.html().replace(searchPattern, "<ACRONYM class='srch'>" + searchString + "</ACRONYM>"));
```

Where, `$elem` is the jQuery object for the HTML element you are searching in. For example, if it is a particular div like `<div id='me'>some text</div>` and you are searching for text "*some*", then it will be like this:

```
var searchPattern = new RegExp('some', 'g');
$elem = $('#me');
$elem.html($elem.html().replace(searchPattern, "<ACRONYM class='srch'>" + searchString + "</ACRONYM>"));
```

Give appropriate highlight style for the css class '*srch*'. Do not forget to remove the '*acronym*' element with '*srch*' class once your searching is over.